# Android SQLite Query with foreign key using stORM or an alternative

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, greendao, android-storm

I have the following models

```
categories(id, name)
places(id, name, category_id)
```

i have a list view which displays Content based on the categories the user wants to see.

Data for Categories

```
1, River
2, Hill Station
3, Wild Life
4, Temples
```

If the user wants to see places of only category_id = 2 and 4.

How can i do a query to the database to give back a list of places which have category_id = 2 and 4.

I am using [stORM](https://code.google.com/p/storm-gen/) library for the Database.

They have the following functions to do a query.

```
dao.listAll();
dao.listByExample(exampleObj);
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with stORM but you can accomplish this with an "IN" query.

Comment: @Nix yeah i was trying to see how i can use the IN in stORM. Looks like will have to wait till stORM gets out of alpha into a stable release. any other ORM based Lib u suggest ?

Comment: I would suggest you update the title/question to let people know that you are trying to find out how to do it in stORM, or looking for an alternative orm.

Comment: I just looked through the source, and its not possible.  I am not looking to see if i can find any good alternatives.

Comment: @Nix thanks buddy. i guess i will have to either use the sqlitehelper class or find a good orm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you switch to greenDAO, you can use a QueryBuilder, which supports IN and the likes:
http://greendao-orm.com/documentation/queries/

Answer (score 0):

I use ormlite for this purpose.  Check out section in the [docs about the query-builder](http://ormlite.com/docs/query-builder).